# Need to automate an SMB path into a UNC path before sending to Win10 clients

Tags: network, applescript, automator, smb

New here, but I'm having difficulty putting together an AppleScript that will basically take an SMB link and turn it into a UNC link before I send it over to a couple of Win10 clients.

All same network, we're all using a SNS NAS and it's for Adobe Premiere links. We can do this all manually, but the editors don't have time/patience to convert each link. We're looking for an automated script that we could integrate as a service that will convert selected text.

I found the article below, but it's the reverse to what we're looking for. I tried reversing all of the functions in it but wasn't able to get it to run properly.

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2211017

It'd also be awesome if the 'service' that is created simple copies the entry into the clipboard so that the end-user can paste it into a couple of different things like email and Slack messenger.

Hopefully someone can help or steer me in the right direction. I've been scouring Google for this for about a week.

EDIT** Examples below

Old path
'smb://server/folder'

New path
'\\server\folder'

Comment: I deleted my original answer after some comments by klanomath because at the time it was late and needed to sleep. I've added a caveat, the note at the top of my answer, and undeleted it. Hopefully as an example it covers your needs however if you need more than that, then undated your question accordingly and if you need additional help with the coding I'll see what I can do for you.

Answer (score 5):

maybe a little late to the party, but we use a 3rd party app for this at work

[linkconverter](https://apps.apple.com/app/linkconverter/id1604758881?l=en&mt=12)

works pretty well, especially that you can rightclick any file on an UNC Drive and copy the pathname to get the windows result

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: This answer is intended only as an example when the SMB Path, aside from the colon, slashes and backslashes and without spaces, only contains alphanumeric characters in the name! If you need to account for anything else, i.e. read the comments to this answer, you'll need to modify the code according to your needs. That said, in all of my years as a Network Systems Administrator and Network Systems Engineer I never created shares containing spaces or other then the need for colons, slashes, backslashes and alphanumeric characters and therefore this simple example is all that I'd need to translate any, e.g. `smb://server/folder` to `\\server\folder`, SMB Path I ever used to a UNC Path. YMMV!

---

In **Automator**, create a new **Service** *workflow*, then add a **Run AppleScript** *action* to it while replacing the default **AppleScript** *code* with the *code* below:

```
on searchReplace(theText, SearchString, ReplaceString)
    set OldDelims to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to SearchString
    set newText to text items of theText
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ReplaceString
    set newText to newText as text
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to OldDelims
    return newText
end searchReplace

on run {input, parameters}
    set selectedText to item 1 of input as string
    set convertedText to searchReplace(selectedText, "smb://", "\\\\")
    set convertedText to searchReplace(convertedText, "/", "\\")
    set the clipboard to convertedText as string
    return convertedText
end run
```

Then save the **Service** as: **Convert SMB Path to UNC Path**

Now **Convert SMB Path to UNC Path** will appear on the **Services** *menu* or **Services** *context menu* when *text* is *selected* and when the **Service** is used, the **UNC Path** is placed on the **Clipboard**. (This of course assumes the *selected text* was actually an **SMB Path**, otherwise what's placed there is just whatever *text* was *selected* when the **Service** was run which will include any substitutions made.)

Example **SMB Path** `smb://server/folder` will be converted to **UNC Path** `\\server\folder` and placed on the **Clipboard**.

**Note:** Note the settings of the **Service** in the image below. The **Output replaces selected text** *checkbox* is unchecked. You may check it, if that's what you want, however, if the *selected text* is not actually replaceable then the **Service** will not appear on the **Services** *menu* or **Services** *context menu*.

[image: Convert SMB Path to UNC Path Automator Service]

Comment: What happens when the SMB path contains spaces or `\ `  escaped spaces?

Comment: @klanomath, Hadn't though about that! I guess the first substitution could be `set convertedText to searchReplace(selectedText, "\\", "")` which will remove any backslashes and thus I assume handle an escaped space. Can UNC Paths have spaces? If yes, should a UNC Path having space be quoted?

Comment: AFAIK UNC paths containing spaces should be quoted **in Windows**. Escaping them or a %20 probably won't work

Comment: @klanomath, So then, I should add the suggested code of my first comment and then have the `convertedText`, which will be the UNC Path placed on the Clipboard and have it quoted whether of not it has spaces would still be okay quoted? I'm not able to test at the moment and why I'm asking for your input. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm it's OK but ugly. I also recommend to post a warning when the POSIX path contains `<>|?*"`.

Comment: You guys rock, we're going to play around with this today and tomorrow! Thanks!!