# How to use AppleScript to change an IP address in copied text

Tags: applescript, automator, copy-paste

Basically I need to search in clipboard contents for an IP address and replace it with an address that's in a completely different subnet: (10.10.8.24 to 192.168.8.24 as examples). I tried using the find and replace template in Automator but it simply wasn't working with copied text. I'm also kind of a noob with AppleScript syntax.

Comment: You said "_I need to search for 10.10.8.24 in clipboard contents and change it to 192.168.10.11 as examples._", so can you please edit your question adding more details, because saying "_as examples_" make this a bit broad and lacking in real details. Are these IP Addresses the only substitution you're trying to make or what? How and when did the info get placed on the clipboard, is there a possibility the substitution can be made before it get to the clipboard? Is the Clipboard content formatted or plain text? Etc.!

Comment: Were coping a full SMB path out of Finder and then pasting it into slack. Ideally I have another service working thanks to a few users over at my other post: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/281156/need-to-automate-an-smb-path-into-a-unc-path-before-sending-to-win10-clients ~ but it'd be super beneficial if I were able to combine both of these scripts into one. Changing the clipboard contents from smb://10.10.8.24/folder over to \\192.168.10.24\folder and then the ol' paste command will drop the results wherever you want.

Comment: You **have not addressed** all what I asked in my first comment to your question! Is `10.10.8.24` to `192.168.10.11` IP Address substitution the only one you need to make or are there other IP Address you need to substitute. Again I implore you to edit your question adding the appropriate details!

Comment: If you are wanting to do this in conjunction with the other question, (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/281156), why can't you make the substitution within the example already presented!? The `on searchReplace(theText, SearchString, ReplaceString)` _handler_ is fully capable of making the substitution! After the `set convertedText to searchReplace(selectedText, "smb://", "\\\\")` line of _code_ use, e.g., `set convertedText to searchReplace(convertedText, "10.10.8.24", "192.168.10.11")`. You can add that as many times for as many pairs of IP Addresses you need to substitute.

Comment: Ok so I'm starting to wrap my mind around AppleScript. Getting down votes but oh well. It's all starting to come together. Thanks for the elevated help @user3439894 !!

Comment: charmndr, you're probably getting down-voted because your question does not have adequate details as well as you have not fully answered the questions asked in the comments. If you'd edit your OP to include the missing information so is was clear, concise and complete and showed some effort on your part, then you'll probably get up-votes instead. I know I'd up-vote the question if it was clear, concise and complete and showed some effort on your part. Heck I'd probably even post an answer too. Which you'd then hopefully mark as the accepted answer if it correctly answered your question. :)

Comment: I edited it earlier as per your request, but also tried the convertedText line that you added in above and replicated it using 10 different IP addresses. Everything seems to be working now. Down votes are whatever, it's the internet, I'm 30 and I'm totally used to it. I'm also not a programmer or a script wizard ;) appreciate the help...

Answer (score 1):

You can use this shell command to check for clipboard contents and replace them:

```
[[ $(pbpaste) == "10.10.8.24" ]] && printf "192.168.10.11" | pbcopy
```

Basically, this checks if the current clipboard (which pbpaste outputs) is equal to the first string. If it is, it pipes the output of the printf command to pbcopy, which writes to the clipboard. You can add this to an AppleScript and have it repeat with:

```
repeat
    do shell script "[[ $(pbpaste) == \"10.10.8.24\" ]] && printf \"192.168.10.11\" | pbcopy; exit 0"
    delay 1
end repeat
```

(You have to doctor it up a bit with the \ and ; exit 0 so it runs in AppleScript, but this should check every second and replace the clipboard)

Comment: Your first part of the answer assumes that the clipboard only contains an IP Address, which may or may not be the case as it certainly isn't clear from the OP. Also, what's with the endless repeat loop triggering every second? There is absolutely nothing whatsoever in the OP looking to do an endless loop and even if there was, how are you going to break out of the endless loop!? **Never post code that causes an endless loop without also providing a programatic way of breaking out of the endless loop!**

Comment: Yes, sorry and late to the party. I should have clarified that this would be ideal as a Service menu item. Is that pretty easy to implement? I'll see what I can find with what Leo said above but it kind freaks me out regarding an endless loop LOL.